# MySQL Server 8.0 won't start on Ubunut 23

Tags: ubuntu, mysql-8.0

I've installed MySQL using

```
sudo apt install MySQL-Server
```

But it won't start. Just states that it's activating and that's it.

This is what I get after running

```
systemctl status mysql.service
journalctl -xeu mysql.service
```

```
 mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: oom-kill) since Sat 2023-07-29 08:01:47 PDT; 227ms ago
    Process: 2378 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 2386 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=killed, signal=KILL)
   Main PID: 2386 (code=killed, signal=KILL)
     Status: "Server startup in progress"
        CPU: 2.649s

Jul 29 08:01:47 ubuntu systemd[1]: mysql.service: A process of this unit has been killed by the OOM killer.
Jul 29 08:01:47 ubuntu systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Jul 29 08:01:47 ubuntu systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'oom-kill'.
Jul 29 08:01:47 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start mysql.service - MySQL Community Server.
Jul 29 08:01:47 ubuntu systemd[1]: mysql.service: Consumed 2.649s CPU time.
Jul 29 08:01:47 ubuntu systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 71.
Jul 29 08:01:47 ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped mysql.service - MySQL Community Server.
Jul 29 08:01:47 ubuntu systemd[1]: mysql.service: Consumed 2.649s CPU time.
Jul 29 08:01:47 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting mysql.service - MySQL Community Server...
:~$ journalctl -xeu mysql.service
Jul 29 08:02:43 ubuntu systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 76.
░░ Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ Automatic restarting of the unit mysql.service has been scheduled, as the result for
░░ the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Jul 29 08:02:43 ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped mysql.service - MySQL Community Server.
░░ Subject: A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 8529 and the job result is done.
Jul 29 08:02:43 ubuntu systemd[1]: mysql.service: Consumed 2.685s CPU time.
░░ Subject: Resources consumed by unit runtime
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ The unit mysql.service completed and consumed the indicated resources.
Jul 29 08:02:43 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting mysql.service - MySQL Community Server...
░░ Subject: A start job for unit mysql.service has begun execution
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit mysql.service has begun execution.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 8529.
```

Regardless of how many times I purge, clean, autoremove, and update. I still get the same thing.

Comment: How much RAM is available on the server?  # CPU's/Cores?  Could you post complete content of my.cnf for analysis and from the OS  TOP or HTOP results from first page?  The indication is you are OOM (out of memory).  What version of MySQL had you been using before this problem?

Comment: I discovered it was due to the raspberry pi ubuntu iso. The solution was to use mariadb instead.

Comment: Great. Glad you resolved your issue with MariaDB. For performance tuning view profile for contact info.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to using the raspberry pi ubuntu iso instead of a clean ubuntu iso. I used MariaDB as a work around for this. The set up is relatively similar if not the same for MySQL. I'm using it with JDBC so it worked out well in regards to working with the connector.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mariadb-server
sudo apt install libmariadb-java
```